# can a div be .appended by calling "outside" function?

Tags: d3.js

```
.append("div", function(d) {return createTestDiv(d)});

function createTestDiv(d) {
    var d1= document.createElement( 'div' );
    var svg = d3.select(d1).append("svg");
    return d1;
}
```

is what I am trying to do. createTestDiv is called with good data(d) but a stock div is displayed without a child svg. svg is just example, I do not think the created div is even coming from createTestDiv() due to  .append("div", function(d) {return createTestDiv(d)}); being suspect syntax.

Comment: Just remove the "div" and only give the function to `.append()`.

Comment: thank you so much - makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append):

> The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append.

So all you need to do is give the function as the only argument to `.append()`.